# Post or Put multiple items in a single request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to `Post` or `Put` more than a single item at a time, in a single request?

From

```
GET  /api/books Get all books.

POST /api/books Create a new book.

PUT /api/books/{id} Update an existing book.
```

To

```
POST /api/books Create books.

PUT /api/books  Update books.
```

Comment: You could have the endpoint and method signature take a `List<Book>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a class called `Book`, defined as:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

Now we have a simple Web.Api controller with a POST method:

```
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("books")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostBooks([FromBody] IEnumerable<Book> books)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

The method doesn't do anything with the data, it's purely so it compiles and runs. My first attribute indicates this is a POST, the second attribute determines the route, I'm using [attribute based routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) because I just like it more, but you can roll your own routing rules.

Now the `PostBooks` method takes in a parameter of type `Ienumerable<Book>`, not just a single parameter of type `Book`.

When I now stand up this little endpoint, and hit it with the following url:

> http://localhost:port/books

And specify the request to be a `POST` and supply the following payload in the body of the request:

```
[  
   {  
      "Title":"This is a book",
      "Author":"Joe Bloggs"
   },
   {  
      "Title":"This is a book: The reckoning",
      "Author":"Joe Bloggs"
   }
]
```

My breakpoint is hit and Web.API managed to deserialize my payload into the `books` parameter when it comes into the `PostBooks` method:

[image: booksDeserialized]

The same applies for a `PUT`, the only thing that needs changing is the attribute.

Comment: @Sha-Pai Li - Then don't forget to accept it if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use like below's code.

```
   // Post Multi
    // POST: api/books
    [Route("api/books")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Book>))]
    public IHttpActionResult Postbooks(IEnumerable<Book> books)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        foreach (var item in books)
        {
            db.Book.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {

            throw;

        }

        return Ok(books);
    }
```